# Spring Boot - HttpSession object in HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Tags: spring-boot

`HandlerInterceptorAdapter` interface provides following two objects `HttpServletRequest , HttpServletResponse` implicitly. But it does not provide `HttpSession` object implicitly. Any way to access the `HttpSession` object in interceptor

Answer (score 0):

You can get the session object from `HttpServletRequest.getSession()`